# How to pass an array to a function in c

Tags: arrays, function, unresolved-external

I am new to C++ programming and just learned about arrays. I am trying to use an array as a parameter of a function and the program fails to compile. To be more specific this is my code:

```
int main ()
{
int values [10],i;

cout<<"Enter 10 values: "<<endl;

for (i=0; i<10;i++)
{
    cin>>values[i];
}

    // This is the function to which I want to send the array.
getmaxmin (values, 10); 

}
```

I get an error message that says: "unresolved external symbols in function main". What does that mean?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare the function *before* you use the function and **define** any *Declared* functions?

```
int function();//declaration

//...
function();//call

//...
int function()//definition
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all declare the function before you call it,

```
int getmaxmin(int values[10]);  //Prototype


getmaxmin (values); // Call

int getmaxmin (int values[10])
{

  // Define

}
```

In this manner you can pass arrays in C++.